# Java: Display Clients IP and port numbers

Tags: java, udp

Hello I've written a small UDP server program. 
I know the code to display the hosts IP is easy with the following code:

```
System.out.println("Listening Port: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
System.out.println("IP: " + myIp.getHostAddress());
```

Is there a way of displaying the IP and port number of the Client who is connected to the server?

Comment: This is TCP code. Are you sure you mean UDP?

Answer (score 3):

When you receive your UDP `DatagramPacket` you can retrieve the distant IP from where the packet originated by `DatagramPacket.getAddress()`

**EDIT**
If you wish to get the string representation of the IP address, just use `DatagramPacket.getAddress().toString()`.

Example:

```
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 
buffer.length); 
ds.receive(p);  // Receive data here... 
System.out.println("Received data packet from :"+p.getAddress().toString());
```

Comment: I tired this String clientip = DatagramPacket.getAddress(); But I get this error Type mismatch: cannot convert from InetAddress to String. Can you give me an example of the code how to do that please?

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAddress() from the type DatagramPacket. Thanks that helped but I got this error now haha

Comment: Good, we are moving towards the goal :) Please see my edit for a complete example on how to use that

Answer (score 1):

About that sample: `String clientip = DatagramPacket.getAddress();`
why don't you just cast it to `String`.

```
String clientip = (String) DatagramPacket.getAddress();
```

Though i don't really have a Java Compiler at the moment. but just try that. Will get back really soon.